# Spectral radius of "almost" regular graph ?!

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

The answer to this question could be trivial.

**The Graph** Let $G$ be graph formed of two $d$-regular connected components. That is, $G= H_1\cup H_2$, where $H_1$, and $H_2$ are $d$-regular and disjoint. Let $x\in H_1$ and $y\in H_2$. Let $G'= G+xy$, then $G'$ is connected graph. My question is:

**Question:** What is the largest positive  eigenvalue of $G'$  ? Or $\lambda_1 (G') = ??$

**Ideas:**

-It is obvious that $\lambda_1 (G) = d$ with multiplicity 2 ( since it is formed of 2 $d$-regular connected components). But I have no idea how to estimate $\lambda_1$ when a single  edge is added between $H_1$, and $H_2$.

-The [interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) could help in commutating  bound for the maximal eigenvalue.

Any idea will be useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the interlacing result you mentioned is that $\lambda_1(G') \geq \lambda_2(G)=d$.  For the other direction, Weyl's inequality (the triangle inequality for spectral radius) tells you 
$$\lambda_1(G') \leq \lambda_1(G) + \lambda_1(G-G')=d+1,$$
but I think we can say something stronger.

Suppose we have 
$$A'v = \lambda v $$
where $A'$ is the adjacency matrix of $G'$.  Assume WLOG that $|v(x)| \geq |v(y)|$, and let $z$ be a vertex having maximal $|v(z)|$ among all vertices other than $x$ and $y$.  Using the triangle inequality and the eigenvalue definition, we have 
$$\lambda |v(x)| = |(A' v) x | \leq \sum_{w \sim x} |v(w)| \leq |v(x)| + d |v(z)|$$
(the $d$ neighbors of $x$ in $H_1$ each contribute at most $|v(z)|$, and $y$ contributes at most $|v(x)|$).   Similarly, 
$$\lambda |v(z)| = |(A' v) z| \leq \sum_{w \sim z} |v(w)| \leq |v(x)| + (d-1) |v(z)|$$

Let $v'=\left(\begin{array}{c} |v(x)| \\ |v(z)| \end{array}\right)$, and let $M=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & d \\ 1 & d-1\end{array}\right)$.  The above inequalities tell us 
$$0 \leq \lambda v' \leq M v'$$
in each coordinate, so we have 
$$\lambda ||v'|| \leq ||M v'|| \leq ||M|| ||v'|| = \frac{1}{2} (d+\sqrt{d^2+4}) ||v'||$$
So the spectral radius of $G'$ is at most $\frac{1}{2} (d+\sqrt{d^2+4})$.  For large $d$ this is roughly $d+\frac{1}{d}$.

I have a feeling this may be well-known/classical, but don't have a reference.